# Custom Sitecore index not updated on publish after item delete

Tags: azure-search

We are using Sitecore 8.2 with Azure search.
When I delete an item and publish the parent folder, the item goes away from sitecore_web_index, however, it doesnt go away from the custom_web_index. 
(I checked - the item didnt get removed from custom_master_index as well).

When I rebuild the custom indexes - they do get updated and remove the deleted item.

Is there any additional configuration / code required to synchronously keep custom indexes updated?

The index has onPublishEndAsync enabled

```
<index id="custom_web_index" type="Sitecore.Support.ContentSearch.Azure.CloudSearchProviderIndex, Sitecore.Support.145992">
            <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
            <param desc="connectionStringName">cloud.search</param>
            <param desc="totalParallelServices">5</param>
            <!-- Return maximum of 200 facets from search, default is 10 -->
            <maxTermsCountInFacet>200</maxTermsCountInFacet>
            <!-- This initializes index property store. Id has to be set to the index id -->
            <param desc="propertyStore" ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/databasePropertyStore" param1="$(id)" />
            <configuration ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/searchCloudIndexConfiguration" />
            <schemaBuilder ref="contentSearch/searchServiceSchemaBuilder" />
            <searchService type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure.Http.CompositeSearchService, Sitecore.ContentSearch.Azure"/>
            <strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
              <!-- NOTE: order of these is controls the execution order -->
              <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
            </strategies>
            <commitPolicyExecutor type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.CommitPolicyExecutor, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
              <policies hint="list:AddCommitPolicy">
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.TimeIntervalCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch" />
                <policy type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.ModificationCountCommitPolicy, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                  <Limit>1000</Limit>
                </policy>
              </policies>
            </commitPolicyExecutor>
            <locations hint="list:AddCrawler">
              <crawler type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SitecoreItemCrawler, Sitecore.ContentSearch">
                <Database>web</Database>
                <Root>/sitecore/content/site</Root>
              </crawler>
            </locations>
            <enableItemLanguageFallback>true</enableItemLanguageFallback>
            <enableFieldLanguageFallback>true</enableFieldLanguageFallback>
          </index>
```

Comment: Can you show the rest of the custom index config?

Comment: Updated the question with full config @Gatogordo

Comment: Looks like a bug, I know a similar issue in 9.0.0 too

Answer (score 0):

I think we may have had this issue with our site, it's a Sitecore bug, and there's a patch for it. I would go to Sitecore support for this one.

ETA: Sorry, when I looked it up, the issue I remembered was somewhat different; our issue was about *renaming* a media item.

Comment: would you happen to have the support hotfix number? We did reach out to Sitecore but they were unable to help since it was 8.2 and they don't officially support it any more.

Comment: @DurgaBose try taking a look here: https://github.com/search?q=org%3ASitecoreSupport+delete